# Laravel simplify a database query with relations

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm just started to work with Laravel and think its a pretty good framework.
But there is a lot to learn and i can mostly find everything in the user guide except this part:

I'm trying to get items from my database they are sorted with a category id that relates to a other table item_catagories in this table are stored:
id
name
parent

In my url of the website I use the name of the category instead of the id.

```
http://example.com/catagory/subcatagory
```

when subcatagory has a value I want to search for the related items.
I now have it like this:

```
if($subcategory){
    $foo = ItemCategories::where(['group' => $category, 'name'=> $subcategory])
                           ->get()[0]->id;
    $data['products'] = Items::where('category_id', $foo)->get();
}
```

but there must be a much simpler way to get the same results.

I hope someone can help me to understand how I can do it better

**Edit**

I forgot to add the relation code:

The item class:

```
public function categorie(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\ItemCategories');
}
```

The categorie class:

```
public function items(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Items');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel Eloquent's relationships for this. On your category model:

```
public function items() { return $this->hasMany('Items'); }
```

Once you've done that, on a category, you can do `$category->items` to fetch all of its related items.

Incidentally, when you do this:

```
->get()[0]
```

you can just do this:

```
->first()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to bring your results already populated, one way to do this is:

```
$foo = ItemCategories::where(['group' => $category, 'name'=> $subcategory])->with('items')->first();
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I get this fixed:
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'items.item_category_id' in 'where clause' I've the column catagory_id

Comment: Probably items is a collection, so, the collection doesn't have a "category_id" attribute to access directly from the relation.

Comment: No Laravel makes it item_category_id but I've in my table catagory_id.
I want all items from a specific category and the items have a catagory id. so is it possible to do something like Item::all()-with(catagory, 1)
but then in place of the 1 the name "Test" that is id 1 in the table

Comment: Yes, you can do this:
Item::all()-with(['catagory' => function($query) {
$query->where('category_id', 1);
}])